# Spring DWR engine.js failing unknown error

Tags: javascript, java, spring, dwr

We have a web application that is using **Spring framework 5.1.7.RELEASE**, **JDK 1.8** and **DWR 3.0.2** deployed in **WAS 8.5**. We have a JSP web page; that displays some statistical information to its user; web page was working fine like in years and all of a sudden it started failing to load. When we debugged the issue; we narrow it down to dwr's ajax request; and it failed in ***engine.js*** with an unknown error. What we figured; we will provide the information in answer to this question. Code snippet is below, and it continue to fail on line '3' below i.e. ***controllerClass.someMethod*** call. ***selectObj1*** and ***selectObj2*** are array type of objects.

```
if (document.getElementById("someCheckBox").checked) {
    //Below controllerClass is the name of JS class produced by DWR but actually it's a Java class (i.e. object used below)
    controllerClass.someMethod("Value1", selectObj1, selectObj2, 'Value2', 'Value1', function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
         hideView("viewOne",false);     //user defined function call
         fillData("viewName",data[0]);  //user defined function to fill the returned data
         valueRet1 = data[1]; 
         someConst = "X";
         displayNavCon(pageNumber);  //user defined function to control the navigation on web page
      }  else {
        alert("No Data Found!!!");  
        recordCount=0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to DWR and it start's failing with an error in ***engine.js***; I think **DWR** needs to put some improvements there. Because most of the time error is/was unknown. So in above case - we were passing some data in DWR's ajax call using ***selectObj1*** like an array and ***selectObj2*** like an array, how data being constructed haven't changed in years; then we noticed that there was a decimal value being passed in ***selectObj1*** that has comma in it, we removed the comma before giving data to DWR's ajax call and Bingo! it worked. Code fix is below;

```
//we are omitting the construction of other object being passed in i.e. selectObj2
var indexBrkLp = 0;
if (priceVal != null){
    while (priceVal.includes(",")){
        indexBrkLp++;
        priceVal = priceVal.replace(",", "")
        if (indexBrkLp > 5){
            break;
        }
    }
}

var selectObj1={
    val2:(val2 == null? "": val2),
    priceVal :(priceVal == null? "": priceVal)
};

if (document.getElementById("someCheckBox").checked) {
    //Below controllerClass is the name of JS class produced by DWR but actually it's a Java class (i.e. object used below)
    controllerClass.someMethod("Value1", selectObj1, selectObj2, 'Value2', 'Value1', function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
         hideView("viewOne",false);     //user defined function call
         fillData("viewName",data[0]);  //user defined function to fill the returned data
         valueRet1 = data[1]; 
         someConst = "X";
         displayNavCon(pageNumber); //user defined function to control the navigation on web page
      }  else {
        alert("No Data Found!!!");  
        recordCount=0;
    }
});
```

Conclusion - If you see ***engine.js*** is failing, then it might not just be something wrong in your code; it could be data that it don't like or could be some other config related to **DWR**.